# Kafka S3 Source Connector

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I have a requirement where sources outside of our application will drop a file in an S3 bucket that we have to load in a kafka topic.  I am looking at Confluent's S3 Source connector and currently working on defining the configuration for setting up the connector in our environment.  But a couple of posts indicated that one can use S3 Source connector only if you have used the S3 Sink connector to drop the file in S3.

Is the above true?  Where / what property  do I use to define the output topic in  the configuration?  And can the messages be transformed when reading from S3 and putting them in the topic.  Both will be JSON / Avro formats.

Confluent's Quick Start example also assumes you have used the S3 Sink connector, hence the questiion.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received a response from Confluent that it is true that the Confluent S3 Source connector can only be used with the Confluent S3 Sink connector.  It cannot be used independently

Answer (score 2):

Confluent release version 2.0.0 as of 2021-12-15. This version includes [generalized s3 source connection mode](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-s3-source/2.0.0/generalized/overview.html)